# Where to start on basic derivation using $I$ inclusion

Tags: logic

I'm trying to get through the following problem (which uses a negation inclusive ($-I$)) what steps should I take to properly derive this?

$P\rightarrow Q, Q\rightarrow R, - R\vdash -(P\wedge S)$

I am using the following rule sets:

First 7:

https://books.google.com/books?id=qaIdAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA152&lpg=PA152&dq=nelson+p+lande+derivation+rules&source=bl&ots=dZSufOhmlc&sig=Ybw_RboRt2lze1CZqc8iXlyDUfQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjr1aWXp-bTAhXqjFQKHTjJDA0Q6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q&f=false

Last 4:

https://books.google.com/books?id=qaIdAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA192&lpg=PA192&dq=nelson+p+lande+derivation+rules&source=bl&ots=dZSufOhmlc&sig=Ybw_RboRt2lze1CZqc8iXlyDUfQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjr1aWXp-bTAhXqjFQKHTjJDA0Q6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q&f=false

Let me know if there is anything I can do to pose this question in a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{array}{llll}
1&1&P \land S&A\\
1&2&P&1 \land E\\
3&3&P\rightarrow Q&A\\
1,3&4&Q&\rightarrow E\\
5&5&Q\rightarrow R&A\\
1,3,5&6&R&4,5 \rightarrow E\\
7&7&\neg R&A\\
1,3,5,7&8&R\land \neg R&6,7 \land I\\
3,5,7&9&\neg(P\land S)&8 \neg I\\
\end{array}

Comment: Thanks! I started working backwards but I always get stuck when it comes to making the assumptions, need to touch up on those rules.

Comment: @Kellen You,ll pick up the use of $\neg I$ quick enough! But yes, you have to work 'backwards': if ever you need to prove $\neg \varphi$, 9 times out of 10 you need to throw in $\varphi$ as an assumption and derive some kind of contradiction.